How can keys in `process.env` be narrowed in TypeScript without modifying values
Consider the following code:
interface UnvalidatedInputs {
  A: string | undefined;
  B: string | undefined;
}

interface ValidatedInputs {
  a: string;
  b: number;
}

export function validateInputs(processEnv: UnvalidatedInputs): ValidatedInputs {
  const a = processEnv.A;
  const b = Number(processEnv.B);
  if (a === undefined || Number.isNaN(b)) {
    throw new Error("invalid inputs");
  }
  return { a, b };
}

export const VALIDATED_INPUTS = validateInputs(process.env);

This code (in particular validateInputs(process.env)) fails TypeScript type checking with:
Argument of type 'ProcessEnv' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UnvalidatedInputs'.
  Type 'ProcessEnv' is missing the following properties from type 'UnvalidatedInputs': A, B(2345)

But the actual definition of NodeJS.ProcessEnv involves a key type that contains all of "A" | "B" as a subset, roughly:
interface ProcessEnv {
  [key: string]: string | undefined;
  TZ?: string;
}


Note the following "passthrough narrowing" does not have the same issue as the above code, but does "require" a no-op function call to get TypeScript to recognize the narrowed key set:
type Dict<K extends string> = {
  [P in K]: string | undefined;
};

export function identityNarrow<K1 extends string, K2 extends K1>(
  input: Dict<K1>
): Dict<K2> {
  return input;
}

export const NARROWED_PROCESS_ENV: Dict<"A" | "B"> = identityNarrow(
  process.env
);


Somewhat of a sidenote: process is a Node global. You don't import it. Why does your code have import * as process from "node:process"; at all, instead of telling TS that process is external because you're using Node in your TS config? Also, this feels like the exact thing you shouldn't be doing: process.env is the execution environment. you know what's in it because: you control it. You know what's in it, so get data out by name, and tell TS what what that thing is directly. If you're blindly getting values out of process.env using findKey, something's gone terrible wrong.

Sorry, didn't mean to draw emphasis to that import, I'll remove it!

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans This is more a question about why the type narrowing doesn't work.
As for why one may want to introduce a findKey() helper, it may be to provide documentation or validation (via types) that only a subset of keys are allowed or expected to be used.

That's literally what an interface is for. It doesn't matter if "the thing" has more values in it, the interface says that any TS code only has access to the named properties. You just go cons env = process.env as theInterfaceItShouldBe and off we go. To quote a phrase, "anyone can design a bridge, but it's the engineer's job to design a bridge that can only support what's needed". The best TS specifies the least, because any TS decoration just makes it exponentially harder to maintain.

Totally, and that was where I started. An interface where type narrowing didn't occur. (I thought the move abstract and possible more contrived code I have here would be helpful to readers but it seems I was mistaken. I'll modify to my original intent.)

Totally hear you on the complexity of TypeScript (e.g. nested generics) @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans; using type assert (as) is something I was trying to avoid since it does an end-around on the actual type system.
Really maybe this should've been a GitHub issues against TypeScript given the fact that identityNarrow() works fine but validateInputs() cannot accept process.env

But that's what it should do? process is outside of TS's control. It's even outside of Node's control: it's the definition of an external. This is literally when as is the correct typing. You say what it should be, because you know what it's set up to be, completely outside of anything TS/JS related. It's the execution environment: it exists regardless of which thing happens to be running, be that Node, Python, a CI/CD runner, or the latest AAA game =P

To get rid of the "type ProcessEnv is missing the following properties from type UnvalidatedInputs" error, you should declare the UnvalidatedInputs properties as optional (i.e. A?: string | undefined, not just | undefined). However that leads to a "as no properties in common" type error :-/

Why not simply declare function validateInputs(processEnv: ProcessEnv): ValidatedInputs {…}?

To build on what @Bergi said, if you really want a type to hold your unvalidated inputs you could create an intersection type such as type UnvalidatedInputs = NodeJS.ProcessEnv & { A?: string, B?: string }.
